# Compute complex integral inside an open curve

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, residue-calculus, complex-integration

I need to compute this **complex** integral:

$$ \int_\gamma \frac{1}{(z-i)(z-2i)} dz $$

$\gamma$ is defined as:

$$ \gamma (t) = t + i(3e^t\cos^2(t)) $$

The parameter *t* belongs to the following interval: $[\frac{-\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}] $

My approach to this question was to use the **Residue's Theorem.** However, the theorem requires a **closed curve**.

The problem above does not portray a closed curve. It is an open one.

I know that open curves can be manipulated as closed ones. You treat it artificially as a closed one and, by the end, you take out (or add) something.

How can I approach this integral?

The partial result of the residues is:

$Res(f,i)= i$ and  $Res(f,2i)=-i$

Hence:

$2\pi i(+i-i)=0 $

P.S.: I also tried a different approach with the formula:

$$ \int f(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)dt $$

Nonetheless, this approach results in a massive and ugly integral. I think the correct approach is the manipulation described above.

---

UPDATE

Professor Robert Israel commented bellow and suggested using a third approach with $F(\gamma(\pi/2)) - F(\gamma(-\pi/2))$. In order to do that, I needed to find the primitives. I got them with a little help from Wolfram Alpha. As you can see bellow, the primitive is not really friendly. I am still curious on how to solve this problem treating the curve as a closed one and manipulating it:
[image]

Comment: The point is that to do it with primitives, which is really the easiest way, you need to split the integral up as in my answer, and then define an appropriate branch of the complex logarithm, as Dr. Israel says. Then, the result falls out. Wolfram is giving you an antiderivative using the Log function, which is not analytic in any open set containing $\gamma$, so it won't work.

Comment: I don't know why Wolfram alpha's giving you such a complicated-looking primitive, but it really isn't. Use partial fraction decomposition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a brute force approach. First, decompose the integrand:

$\int_\gamma \frac{1}{(z-i)(z-2i)} dz=i\int_\gamma \frac{1}{z-i} dz-i\int_\gamma \frac{1}{z-2i} dz.$

Now, treat each one separately:

For the first integral, complete $\gamma $ to a closed curve $\Gamma$ by taking $\gamma_1$ to be the circular arc centered at $z=i$ of radius $|i-\pi/2|$ going from $x=-\pi/2$ to $x=\pi/2$ and find that the angle $\theta $ subtended by this arc is given by $\cos \frac{1}{2}\theta=\frac{1}{|i-\pi/2|}.$ Then, $i\int_{\gamma_1} \frac{1}{z-i} dz=-\theta.$

Now, the argument principle applies to show that $i\int_{\Gamma} \frac{1}{z-i} dz=i(2\pi i)(1)=-2\pi.$

Therefore, $i\int_{\Gamma} \frac{1}{z-i} dz=i\int_{\gamma_1} \frac{1}{z-i} dz-i\int_{\gamma} \frac{1}{z-i} dz\Rightarrow \int_{\gamma} \frac{1}{z-i} dz=i\theta-2\pi i$.

The second integral is treated in the same way, this time with a circle centered at $2i$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: find an antiderivative $F$  of the integrand that is analytic in a region containing the curve $\gamma$.  For this it suffices that any branch cuts are on the imaginary axis below $2i$.
Then the integral is $F(\gamma(\pi/2)) - F(\gamma(-\pi/2))$.

Comment: Thanks, Professor Israel. I had a go on your suggestion with a little help from Wolfram Alpha. The primitive I got is not really nice: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+1%2F((z-i)(z-2i))+dz